# Terrible ping times between wireless / wired subnets

Tags: networking, wifi

I have a SonicWall router configured as follows:

```
P0 = Wired LAN (192.168.1.1)
P1 = Internet
P3 = Sonicpoint WAP  (192.168.5.1)
P3-A = Private Wireless LAN VLAN 1 (192.168.6.1)
P3-B = Public Wireless LAB VLAN 2 (192.168.7.1)
```

If a computer is on P3-A their IP address would be `192.168.6.2` and their gateway would be `192.168.5.1`

If I ping any internet site (google.com) I get sub 30ms responses.

If I ping an address on P0 (192.168.1.4), the ping time varies wildly between 2ms and 2000ms - more so than not it's about ~800ms.

Any suggestions as to identify why I can ping the internet with a consistent response but can't ping the local 192.168.1.x subnet without?

Comment: What happens when you try pinging locally with larger packets? Say a 1400byte ping rather than the default 64.

Comment: If a computer is on P3-A and has an IP of 192.168.6.2 with a DG of 192.168.5.1 then you probably have a misconfigured network.

Comment: I wager that P3 is misconfigured. What is the subnet mask on the interface?

Comment: 255.255.255.0 on all interfaces.

Comment: Ok, I believe I have it fixed, but I'll hold off on the official answer for a few days to verify.  Apparently if "Enable RF Monitoring" is enabled, you'll suffer "extreme latency and completely unreliable connections."  Par for the course.  It is now off - no dropped packets, almost constant 2ms pings, I'll follow up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had more problems even after disabling RF Monitoring, but upgrading the Sonicwall to SonicOS 5.8.0.3 (which also upgrades the Sonicpoints) seems to have alleviated the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling "Enable Aggregation" if you are using the 802.11n radio on the SonicPoint.  That caused me lots of grief when iPads/iPhones were using the network.  After unchecking the box, the effect was immediate.